# How can I define the majority function?

Tags: function-construction

I came across the [majority function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function) while falling into a Wikipedia link rabbit hole (I wish I could remember how I got there...)

The function is defined for $n$ arguments and given by
$$\mathrm{maj}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\left\lfloor\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_n-\frac{1}{2}}{n}\right\rfloor$$
It's easy enough to define the function for a predefined list. For example, given the list

```
t = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10]
(* {0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1} *)
```

I can compute the "majority" with

```
Floor[1/2 + (Sum[t[[i]], {i, 1, Length[t]}] - 1/2)/Length[t]]
(* 1 *)
```

Is there a way to define $\mathrm{maj}$ in a way similar to, say, `f[x_, y_]`?

Comment: If you are interested of the Boolean-valued majority function, you don't need to look further than `Majority` (which is a special case of `BooleanCountingFunction`). Consider `Majority@@(# == 1 & /@ IntegerDigits[num, 2])`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Total` instead of your `Sum`:

```
Clear[maj]
maj[list_?VectorQ] := Floor[1/2 + (Total[list] - 1/2)/Length[list]]

maj[{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}]
(* Out: 1*)
```

---

If you want to work with truth values, the [`Majority`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Majority.html) function is built-in (thanks to [@kglr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/125/kglr) for pointing that out!).

If you'd like, however, you can write your own by applying [the definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function) directly:

```
majBoole[list_?VectorQ] := Count[list, True] >= Length[list]/2

majBoole[{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1} /. {1 -> True, 0 -> False}]
(* Out: True *)
```

Comment: if the input is a list of truth values you can also use the built-in function [Majority](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Majority.html) (+1)

Comment: @kglr Cool, I didn't know that the built-in existed! I should follow my own oft-repeated advice and consult the docs first :-)

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked for a form like `f[x_, y_]`, one can define a pure function which takes an arbitrary number of arguments using `SlotSequence`:

```
maj = Floor[1/2 + (Total[{##}] - 1/2)/Length[{##}]] &;
maj[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
(* 1 *)
```

Alternatively, using `BlankSequence`:

```
maj[ins__] := Floor[1/2 + (Total[{ins}] - 1/2)/Length[{ins}]]
```